# Как быть если украдут RefreshToken?

Tags: безопасность, jwt, token

Представим ситуацию когда мы храним Access и Refresh токены у юзера в localstorage , и кто-то у него их подсмотрел и скопировал . И получается , что теперь у данного злоумышленника есть бессрочный доступ к профилю юзера . Как можно предотвратить подобный случай ?

Answer (score 0):

Не бессрочный, а на время жизни refresh-токена. Плюс с этого момента приложение реального пользователя вылетит из аккаунта. А вообще надо обеспечить сохранность этих данных — если злоумышленник получит логин с паролем, то у него тоже будет доступ, причем реально бессрочный. Из localstorage в целом никто, кроме держателя устройства, не получит его, а при передаче надо использовать https.